# Non Pseudometric Topology Example

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there any example of a Topology which is not pseudo-metrizable (I'm not sure whether the term is correct)?

I understand that the necessary condition for metrizable Topology is whether the Topology satisfies the Hausdorff property. Is there any similar condition for pseudo-metrizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider the Sierpinski space: the underlying set is $\{0,1\}$ and the topology is given by the basis $\{\{1\}\}$. That is, $\{1\}$ is open but $\{0\}$ is not. If this space were pseudometrizable, then the function which interchanges the points would have to be a homeomorphism, because a pseudometric is symmetric.

More generally, a necessary condition for pseudometrizability is the following: if $a,b$ are points which are *not* separated by open sets, then they must have pseudo-distance 0. Hence, they are topologically indistinguishable: that is, for each open set, they either both belong to that open set or both do not. So if you have two topologically distinguishable points which are not separated by open sets, you have a non-pseudometrizable space.

Comment: Your basis needs to be $\{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ in order for it to cover the whole space.

Comment: Thanks @MeesdeVries for your answer. Sorry I still don't understand why Serpinski space is non-pseudometrizable.

Excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Pseudoquasimetrics) says: _A very basic example of a pseudoquasimetric space is the set {0,1} with the premetric given by d(0,1) = 1 and d(1,0) = 0. The associated topological space is the Sierpiński space._ Why can't we define a pseudeometric such that d(0,1) = d(1,0) = 1? What properties does it violate by defining in this way? Thanks!

Comment: @AbeVallerian, you can define that space. In fact, you'll note that $d$ is even a metric, not just a pseudometric. However, the resulting topological space is *not* the Sierpinski space, it is the discrete space on two points, a space where both $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open. Indeed, the Sierpinski space *is* a pseudoquasimetrizable space, but not a pseudometrizable space.